# Typescript call method from child class returns incorrect type

Tags: javascript, typescript

Having two classes. Parent class implements all methods, child class only supplements or overrides those it needs.

```
class Parent<M extends typeof BaseModel> {
  model: M 
  getList(){
     return this.model.queryList()
  }
}

class Child extends Parent<typeof MyModel>{
  model: typeof MyModel
  
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.model = MyModel;
  }
}

const childProvider = new Child();

childProvider.getList() // returns BaseModel.queryList() result instead of MyModel.queryList() result
```

Any idea how I can improve this so I don't need to overwrite every single method from the parent class but when using parent methods, they should be casting proper types.

Comment: is `MyModel` a type or a value?

Comment: Good point. For sake of simplicity, I showed here not very correct typing. It is a value and in my code I refer to it as `typeof MyModel` let me edit my question code snippet.

Comment: please share reproducible example

Comment: The answer is in `typeof MyModel`. The problem was in objection.js typing issues and probably I can avoid those with some small issues on provider side. Anyway, that is resolved now, sorry for bugging you guys.

Comment: Since BaseModel.queryList and MyModel.return different result they do not share same contract. Can you share reproducible example? You can use https://www.typescriptlang.org/play